# TelegramBot not working as Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, bots, telegram

I have developed a simple Telegram Bot using the library

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/

I'm using .NET 5.0 as platform, and a simple command line application. Everything is working if I run it from the command line, but if I start it as a Windows Service (using the .UseWindowsService() method extensions on the host), the bot is not working anymore, but it's not logging any exception.

Do you have any idea about what may be the problem?

Thank you in advance

Sebastiano

Comment: There are plenty of things you can't do as a service that you can as a user application (console or windowed). Without seeing your code, there's no way to help you figure out what it is.

Comment: I found the problem, I still had debugger library that was trying to write to the console...and of course in a Windows Service this is forbidden!